# How to use route in Laravel 5.2 with suffix

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I try

```
 $suffix = '.test';
 Route::get('article/edit/{name?}'.$suffix, ['uses' => 'ArticleController@edit', 'as' => 'Edit']);
```

and it works well. Then I add in auth group, $name always returns with $suffix (for example: $name = 'abc.test')

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
 global $suffix;
       Route::get('article/edit/{name?}'.$suffix, ['uses' => 'ArticleController@edit', 'as' => 'Edit']);
});
```

But I want it returns $name = 'abc';
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score -1):

What if you do?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   global $suffix = '.test';
   Route::get('article/edit/{name?}'.$suffix, [
      'uses' => 'ArticleController@edit',
      'as' => 'Edit'
   ])->where('name', '/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]/');
});
```

Comment: It returns: ErrorException in UriValidator.php line 21: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 31

Comment: Perfect! Do I understand that the topic is closed? :)